# Dependencies between models in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have, besides others, 2 models, WorkDay and Filter. WorkDay contains work units. When the duration of each work unit in a single work day is summed up then you get the work day duration. Additionally, work units have tags assigned to create work specific reports. To filter on tags I have a model called filter that contains a List of tags where to filter on.

Now my issue is, I need to combine those two models. But as far as I understand MVVM, only ViewModels interact with each other. Models don't know other models.

WorkDay (heavily shortened):

```
public class WorkDay
{
    public List<WorkUnit> WorkUnits { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Duration 
    {
        get 
        {
            var duration = TimeSpan.Zero;
            foreach (var workUnit in WorkUnits)
            {
                duration += workUnit.Duration;
            }
            return duration;
        }
    }
}
```

Filter (heavily shortened):

```
public class Filter
{
    public List<String> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

In order to apply the filter to the duration I'd need to kind of inject Filter into WorkDay's Duration property and therefore enable a connection between two models.

```
public class WorkDay
{
    public List<WorkUnit> WorkUnits { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Duration 
    {
        get 
        {
            var duration = TimeSpan.Zero;
            foreach (var workUnit in WorkUnits)
            {
                var filter = ...; // get filter from somewhere?
                if (workUnit.hasAtLeastOneTagFrom(filter))
                    duration += workUnit.Duration;
            }
            return duration;
        }
    }
}
```

Filter should not be a property/field in WorkDay because a filter is applied optionally and can be removed again. I.e. it is just used to calculate and show reports in the UI. So the actual data isn't changed. Furthermore, the UI binds to the Duration property so it's not possible to introduce a method in the following way.

```
public TimeSpan GetDuration(Filter filter) { ... }
```

How can I achieve this in MVVM (MVVMLight) or am I just missing something obvious here?

Comment: you have to create a one class which contains the property of all which you want to access and in your model you have to use that class object as property

Comment: Who said models can't be aware of each other? One model can contain another model, right? MVVM is intended to enforce separation between those layers, not to prevent items in each layer knowing about other items in the same layer.

Comment: @DhavalPatel So you mean I have to introduce a property in WorkDay like so?: `public Filter filter { get; set; }` , set this and use it in Duration later in case it is set?

Comment: yes you can do it what's the prob in it?

Comment: The downside is that I have to assign a filter whenever I want to use filters and remove the filter afterwards again (e.g. going to a new panel).

Comment: There's no problem in a model knowing other models. After all, your WorkDay model already knows your WorkUnit model in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVVM, models can surely know about other models. Actually, you're doing it already in your code: `WorkDay` has a `WorkUnits` property.

It's okay to pass another model to your model. You could create a method which sets the `Duration`field, which in turn is bound to the view.

Answer (score -5):

Use commands. Put your logic inside a command. ViewModel cannot contain any methods, which change state. For MVVMLight you can read about commands [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)

Comment: VMs can contain methods that change state. Why would you say they can't?

Comment: I don't see what commands have to do with this. Commands enable you to bind UI actions to the VM. Why can't a VM change state?

Comment: @slugster Because command should contain this logic. ViewModel is only data placeholder, if you put logic in ViewModel, ViewModel has many possible reasons to be changed, consequently this model does not match SRP. You can read more about this here http://thatextramile.be/blog/2010/07/the-mvvm-pattern-is-highly-overrated/

Comment: That article doesn't even talk about commands and I completely disagree with it's contents. Where would you put the commands anyway, if not in your VM?

Comment: @Bv202 Markup extensions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry Sattar, but I will categorically say that you are wrong. Markup extensions are not for commands (of the ICommand variety), and viewmodels are for both holding data *and shaping or transforming it* for the view.